# How to make Google Calendar API Requests using javascript and a service account?

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) quickstart tutorial for the Google Calendar API using javascript in my web application. As I need the possibility to show Calendar data on the webpage without user login, I need to implement API calls using a Service Account. Unfortunately I cant't find any good tutorials or explanations for doing so in javascript and since I am fairly new to the subject of API programming I kind of need some guidance.

Ty in advance.

Comment: service accounts are [server-side](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: @noogui: this is really a shame as there are cases where a client-server interaction via service account would be perfect (I have such a need and will need to add an extra layer of server side operations)

Comment: Have you finally managed to connect client-side with a service account?

Answer (score 3):

Using Service account on client side is not secure. You may want to switch to a server side implementation for that. Assuming you are familiar with javascript I suggest to follow NodeJS implementation from [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs).

To create Service Account select service account after step 1->a.
[Refer this image for option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnnVK.jpg)

To use Service Account replace the `authorize()` logic with this

```
var email = credentials.client_email;
var key = credentials.private_key;

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  email, null, key, SCOPES
);

jwt.authorize((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }    
  console.log('You have been successfully authenticated: ', data);

  callback(jwt);
});
```

As you are using Service Account you also need to create a calendar in your Gmail account to use. Then go to settings and select *Add People* to share it with *client_email* from your json, then use your Calendar Id (from Calendar settings) in API Call replacing `primary`